# Rescue session is not running in ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

Helo, i would like to know why the rescue section is not being executed. Because I have a node that is below 1500MiB and ansible_lvm.vgs.research is defined

Follow the code:

```
---
- name: Criar lvm no sistema
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Verificar se existe o volume group RESEARCH
      block:
        - name: Se o grupo de volume não existir, uma mensagem de alerta será dada
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg: "O grupo de volume RESEARCH não existe"
          when: ansible_lvm.vgs.research is not defined
        - name: Criar o logical volume no volume group RESEARCH de 1500 MiB
          community.general.lvol:
            vg: research
            lv: data
            size: 1500m
          when: ansible_lvm.vgs.research is defined and ansible_lvm.vgs.research.size_g > '1500 MiB'
      rescue:
        - name: Criar o logical volume no volume group RESEARCH de 800 MiB, caso o tamanho for menor que 1500 MiB
          community.general.lvol:
            vg: research
            lv: data
            size: 800m
          when: ansible_lvm.vgs.research is defined and ansible_lvm.vgs.research.size_g < '1500 MiB'
```

I expected the rescue session to run and create the logical volume with 800MiB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knoMr.png)

Comment: Please format the code properly and post logs as text instead of the screenshots. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Tasks in the `rescue` block are executed [when any task from `block` fails](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks):

> Rescue blocks specify tasks to run when an earlier task in a block fails. This approach is similar to exception handling in many programming languages. Ansible only runs rescue blocks after a task returns a ‘failed’ state. Bad task definitions and unreachable hosts will not trigger the rescue block.

Example:

```yaml
 tasks:
   - name: Handle the error
     block:
       - name: Print a message
         ansible.builtin.debug:
           msg: 'I execute normally'

       - name: Force a failure
         ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false

       - name: Never print this
         ansible.builtin.debug:
           msg: 'I never execute, due to the above task failing, :-('
     rescue:
       - name: Print when errors
         ansible.builtin.debug:
           msg: 'I caught an error, can do stuff here to fix it, :-)'
```

Your example is not the best use for `block`, but if you really want to perform tasks with `rescue` you can add a [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) task to `block` that fails when the condition is met:

```yaml
- name: Fail when volume group RESEARCH less than 1500 MiB
  ansible.builtin.fail:
    msg: Group RESEARCH less than 1500 MiB
  when: ansible_lvm.vgs.research is defined and ansible_lvm.vgs.research.size_g < '1500 MiB'
```

Comment: In addition to that, one can use [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#id7) condition that doesn't require a separate task.

Answer (score 0):

- Create *switch*

```yaml
  switch:
    - case: "{{ research is not defined }}"
      file: research_none.yml
    - case: "{{ research is defined and size_g|int > 1500 }}"
      file: research_1501.yml
    - case: "{{ research is defined and size_g|int <= 1500 }}"
      file: research_1500.yml
```

- Use it to include the tasks

```yaml
    - include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ switch | selectattr('case') | map(attribute='file') }}"
```

---

Optionally, use simpler and robuster *json_query*

```yaml
    - include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ switch | json_query('[?case].file') }}"
```

---

- Create the tasks. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat research_none.yml
- debug:
    msg: O grupo de volume RESEARCH não existe

shell> cat research_1501.yml
- debug:
    msg: Criar o logical volume no volume group RESEARCH de 1500 MiB

shell> cat research_1500.yml
- debug:
    msg: Criar o logical volume no volume group RESEARCH de 800 MiB, caso o tamanho for menor que 1500 MiB
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    switch:
      - case: "{{ research is not defined }}"
        file: research_none.yml
      - case: "{{ research is defined and size_g|int > 1500 }}"
        file: research_1501.yml
      - case: "{{ research is defined and size_g|int <= 1500 }}"
        file: research_1500.yml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: switch
    - include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ switch | selectattr('case') | map(attribute='file') }}"
```